# Display field-group data

Tags: panels

I've added some database fields (8 in all) for a node into a field-group set using the [Field Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group) module. However, I cannot seem to get the data fields to show up for insertion in a node panel page I created to "display" a node page that shows for entering a new node form.

How do I get the fields to show for the relevant Node on the page, without using a view or creating tabs?